# JavaScript parse CSV file and calculate values

Tags: javascript, csv

I need help with this part it's a bit tricky to me.

I have CSV file that I  need to parse it before upload, then calculate data for:

-Show the average of all prices sold
-Count of all houses sold
-Number of crimes in 2011
-The average price per year in the London area

CSV file https://filebin.net/y6enus2t9me358ew

Comment: That data is not consistent. The number of crimes for all of England is zero, yet per smaller area there are non-zeroes. Anyway, you should show your efforts, and pinpoint where exactly you are stuck. Ask one question, not all the questions you need to address.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get it into a relational database? This is the sort of thing DBs were made for.

Comment: I know, but saving csv file into db is optional, this need to be done before upload. Actually this is just a test assigment and I need help.

Comment: Well if you're tasked with writing code to process this data, you'll have to open the file and loop through the contents. Tedious, but not terribly challenging. If you don't need to write code, this is something a spreadsheet can do.